# What's the get_Text() equivalent in python bindings for Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to move from Selenium 1 to Selenium 2. I use python binding however I can not find any `get_text()` functions.

eg. `selenium.find_elements_by_css_selector("locator").get_text()`

Is there such function in python bindings for Selenium/Webdriver ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the '.text' property.

```
element.text
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked out !
The core problem was in wrong function for selecting element.
I should use **find_element_by_css_selector** instead of **find_elements_by_css_selector**

Answer (score 0):

This line of code...

```
selenium.find_elements_by_css_selector("locator").get_text()
```

...have exactly two (2) issues to be addressed.

---

### Details

As per the current documentation `get_Text()` can be implemented in two different approaches:

- Using the [*text*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute: Gets the text of the element.
- Using the [`get_attribute("innerHTML")`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute): Gets the *innerHTML* of the element.

Additionally, *text* attribute or `get_attribute("innerHTML")` can be applied on a *WebElement* but not on *WebElements*. Hence `find_elements*` needs to be replaced with `find_element*`

---

### Solution

Effectively, your line of code will be:

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  selenium.find_element_by_css_selector("locator").text
  ```
- Using `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  selenium.find_element_by_css_selector("locator").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```