# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text' error extracting the text between the starting and ending tag using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Input:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="TestLeaf" align="left" style="width:350px" xpath="1">
    <div>**TestLeaf**</div>
</input>
```

Code in Selenium Python:

```py
textGet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']").get_text
print(textGet)
```

Result: Shows the error

```
"AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'"
```

Please assist me that how to get the text in between the starting and ending tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the get\_Text() equivalent in python bindings for Selenium/Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360939/whats-the-get-text-equivalent-in-python-bindings-for-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

To get the text simply do the following.

```
textGet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']").text
```

.get_text is not the valid way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
"AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'"
```

...implies that in your program you have invoked the `get_text` attribute, which is not a valid [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) attribute. Instead you need to use the **`text`** attribute.

---

### Solution

To print the text *TestLeaf* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']/div").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']/div").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']/div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username' and @value='TestLeaf']/div"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)